# Creating a table in R from Excel file using SQL

Tags: sql, r

Suppose I have an excel file called  `test.csv`  with fields  `A,B`  and  `C` . I want copy the contents of this file into a SQL table using R. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: First you import data in R. Then, push data from R to Sql table

Comment: As written, this question is too broad. Among other considerations, it depends what SQL dialect you're using (e.g. MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, etc.). I suggest you do some Googling for tutorials like [this one](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-an-r-data-frame-to-an-sql-table/).

Comment: First, csv files are not Excel files. Second, SQL table means same as HTML table or English table since SQL is a language. Please qualify with your RDBMS (i.e., Oracle table, SQL Server table, Postgres table). Third, this question is too broad and research online can point you to right direction. Please come back and ask on a specific issue after earnest efforts.

Comment: Of the `DBI` dialects I use (sql server, postgres, sqlite), all of them support `dbWriteTable`. I second Parfait's notion that some research online will point you in the right direction, as the few R/SQL tutorials I've perused have some step of uploading data.

Comment: In addition to @Parfait comments, it would be important to clarify the data, in particular, data size. If your data is small enough (fit in memory) to load it in R, `dplyr` or `dbplyr` is perhaps the easiest. But if your data do not fit in memory, you would need a different approach that most likely will be RDBMS-specific (potgres COPY command, BULK INSERT if SQL Server, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

See: https://db.rstudio.com/dplyr/#connecting-to-the-database

First, create your database in mysql

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE example;
```

Then, if using RStudio:

```
library(readxl)
library(dbplyr)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), 
                      host = "localhost",
                      user = "root",
                      password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
                      db = 'example')

datasets <- read_xlsx(readxl_example("datasets.xlsx"))

copy_to(dest=con, datasets, name = 'iris',
        temporary = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE)

iris.db <- tbl(con, "iris")
iris.db
```